# How can I stop my collision detection from registering multiple times per frame?

Tags: c++, collision-detection

I am working on a side-scroller shooter right now. Everything is working fine along with the collision detection however, my problem is that the collision triggers my health deduction code multiple times per bullet. Here is the code where the bullet hits a turret. Supposedly doing 5.0 damage but instead it randomly does a lot more damage since the collision runs multiple times with just one bullet. How could I prevent this?

```
void TurretCollision()
{
 int BulletNo = 0; 
        int MissileNo = 0;

for (BulletNo = 0; BulletNo < MAX_BULLETS; BulletNo++)
{
    if (Turret[1] == true)
    {
        //cout << TurretH[1];
        if ((BulletX[BulletNo] >= 103 && BulletX[BulletNo] <= 103.09) && (BulletY[BulletNo] <= -38 && BulletY[BulletNo] >= -45))
        {
            BulletActive[BulletNo] = false;
            TurretTrial = TurretTrial - 5.0;

            if (TurretTrial <= 0.0)
            {
                Turret[1] = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: This has nothing to do with OpenGL; removed the tags and edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a BulletCheck[BulletNo] == true condition.

```
if ((BulletX[BulletNo] >= 103 && BulletX[BulletNo] <= 103.09) 
&& (BulletY[BulletNo] <= -38 && BulletY[BulletNo] >= -45 && BulletActive[BulletNo]) == true)
    {
        BulletActive[BulletNo] = false;
        TurretTrial = TurretTrial - 5.0;

        if (TurretTrial <= 0.0)
        {
            Turret[1] = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Haven't thought of that to be honest, kinda rushing the game since it's due in 10 hours and it's 1AM here and no sleep for a few days already.